# Android Studio cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'base-extension'. One of '{codename, tag}' is expected

Tags: android-studio, github, gradle, import

I tried to import a project from GitHub and I was getting this error and failed to import and use this open-source project successfully.
Also, share with me some tips about How to use/import android based projects from GitHub

The project link: https://github.com/maziar-gh/MaterialX.git

complete shown error:

```
failed
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'base- 
extension'. One of '{layoutlib}' is expected.
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'extension- 
level'. One of '{layoutlib}' is expected.
cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'base-            
extension'. No child element is expected at this point.
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'base-    
extension'. One of '{codename, tag}' is expected.
Gradle Sync issues
```

[image: Other errors]

Comment: Same issue, if you managed to solve the issue, you could post your solution as an answer.